# What is the audio output format of Mozilla MediaRecorder and how can I decode ogg format in Java (or Scala)

Tags: java, javascript, audio, ogg, getusermedia

I am recording user voice with the new (non-standard) [Mozilla MediaRecorder API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder). [image: Example logging of binary recording data]

I gather that the format is ogg. But beyond that, how can I find out, let alone configure whether the audio data is using one or two channels, what the frame rate is, etc?

Related question, probably most of this information is encoded within the binary blob with the ogg format, but how do I process the ogg file format in Java or Scala on the server? The standard Sound API in Java does not seem to support Ogg and I have not found any serious looking library to do so in Java or Scala.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think frame rate is applicable for audio blobs, but from an audio blob, the duration, channelCount and sampleRate can be retrieved using the below function. if you do not need the duration, you can do away with the callback, retrieve other two details with a normal return function.

```
function getAudioBlobDetails(blob, callback){
    var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var audio = new Audio(audioURL);
    audio.onloadedmetadata = function(){
        var source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio);
        callback({
            duration: audio.duration,
            channelCount: source.channelCount,
            sampleRate: source.context.sampleRate
        });
    };        
}
```

#### [Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6v001ev0/)

and for the second part about java/ scala libraries I do not have much idea, but one thing you could do is, use `ffmpeg` in server to convert the `ogg` file to a format you are more comfortable with in handling with java libraries.

#### Edit:

so, if you prefer `wav` format, you can use the famous [mattdiamond/Recorderjs](https://github.com/mattdiamond/Recorderjs)
 for retrieving wav blobs, usage is something like:

```
wavRecorder.exportWAV( uploadBlobToServer); // uploadBlobToServer is the function that accepts blob as parameter.
```

Comment: Thx for the answer. I don't like the idea of using `ffmpeg` because ideally this would be streaming. Starting up a new process for every voice command would be noticeably slower than processing the bits in Memory.

Comment: if you are more comfortable with `wav` / `mp3`, there are ways to get blobs in that format in client side( another upside is they work on chrome too), but I believe `ogg` has better quality than `mp3` and much smaller compared to `wav`

Comment: I actually prefer `wav`, for now anyway, just to get things to work since my speech recognition engine works with `wav`